# Memory management interface

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am writing a small particle system in C++ and am yet unsure about how I should manage the particle related data -- should it be stored in a static or dynamic array, in a linked list, some mixture of both, or whatever else one might think of?

At the moment I don't want to make a choice but would rather like to use an abstract class for memory mangement that on the one hand provides me with allocation and deallocation routines and on the other hand takes care of deallocation of the supplied resources in its destructor. I hope that in this way I can change between and test different particle management strategies quickly and transparently.

1) Is this a reasonable thing to do?

2) If yes: Are there any libraries that provide such functionality?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Definitely don't do a linked list

Comment: Hm ok, but why not? I thought that dynamically growing and shrinking memory can be managed well with linked lists, and particles are dying and being born all the time. Also, I don't need access by index.

Comment: The rule of thumb for containers is to use `std::vector` unless you have a reason not to. If you store the items sorted some how in the vector, than you can often find the elements you need using binary search. And the cache friendlyness usually outweighs the O(n) for inserts/deletes for small objects

Comment: @user412173 Well, in theory that would be good. But another thing to consider is whether it is 'cache friendly'. I don't know very much about this, but I think it is reasonable to assume that storing items sequentially is much more friendly on the cache than storing them all over the place.

Comment: vector is more cache friendly than list

Comment: `std::deque` is also an option.

Comment: Check out this page: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/particles-instancing/

Comment: Make a Particle::Allocate() and hide your allocation method in there.

Comment: You could consider a particle pool. Where objects are created and reused to reduce memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is to use `std::vector` unless you really have a reason to chose something else. At the moment you can stick with it. To control memory management at the low level you can supply a `vector` with your own `allocator` in case `std::allocator` which will use `std::new_allocator` should be replaced. If your main concern is extensive deleting and allocating single object than definitely you might consider writing your own user-defined allocator which will allocate from pool of fixed-sized elements organized into linked list, because conventional and more general `oeprator new()` is not efficient in case of many calls to allocate or deallocate objects one at a time.

To test different containers is a reasonable thing IMO, however vector should suffice. In order to decide if

> 1) Is this a reasonable thing to do?

and thus such tests should be covered at all - you have to think about the operations you are going to use extensively.

> 2) If yes: Are there any libraries that provide such functionality?

I don't know about such library.

Comment: piotrus: Thank you, it's surely good to know that generally std::vector is a good choice, and also I wasn't aware of the optional allocator argument! However, I am still confused: won't it slow down the system heavily that whenever I have to delete a particle, the vector implementation has to move all particles that follow in memory?

Comment: if you are going to extensively delete far from begin or end then list is to consider, however think also about allocator I've mentioned

Comment: I don't understand how a user defined allocator in std::vector could help fasten deletions; as far as I understand, it will only tell std::vector where to ask for space when itialializing or resizing, but the problem that lots of space has to be moved on deletion remains?

Comment: @user412173 providing your own allocator you can change this behavior

Comment: piotrus: Seems I don't get it - could you give some reference?

Comment: please read chapter 19 "Iterators and Allocators" in Stroustrup "The C++..." 3rd Edition

Comment: piotrus: It seems that a sensible thing to do would be to use an std::list with a fixed-size memory-pool as allocator - do you agree?

Comment: yes, this sounds reasonably, however try also with vector, vector beats list in many cases due to cache misses from which list suffers

Answer (score 1):

For a particle system you may wish to consider using one `std::vector` for each coordinate, velocity, colour channel etc for each particle. Eg

```
std::vector<float> x(100);
std::vector<float> vx(100);
etc
```

Instead of

```
std::vector<Particle> p(100)
```

This is known as SOA (structure-of-array) rather than AOS (array of structures). The former is more amenable to vectorization.

Comment: Andrew: Thank you very much for indicating these different choices, I will think about it!